# How to see when a bounty was started?

Tags: support, bounty, timestamps

I was wondering which answer would be awarded the bounty for this question:

[Convolutional Neural Network Scale Sensitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327592/convolutional-neural-network-scale-sensitivity)

If I understand correctly the [bounty](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) mechanism, since no answer has been chosen by the OP, the bounty will go to the highest voted answer, written *after* the bounty was started. In this case, I know that two answers were written after the bounty period start, thus I deduce that this answer will get the bounty:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/328554/58675

In general, however, I noted that the start date of a bounty doesn't appear on the question page. So the only way to know which answers were written after the bounty start, is to consider that the bounty period is 7 days, and compare that against the "answered [..]" text at the bottom of the answer, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### A lot of exact timestamps on Stack Exchange can be revealed by mouseover:

[image]

Comment: Note that this is useful in many other circumstances too. E.g. this question is currently displayed as "asked 3 hours ago", but one can find out the exact timestamp by mouseover.

Answer (score 4):

Bounties last one week, so you can get a decent approximation by counting back from when it says it will expire.  If you need a more precise time, click the edit history link (at bottom center), and one of the noted events will be when the bounty was started and by whom.

[image]

Comment: +1. A simpler (?) method is to mouse-over "11 hours" in "This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from Alex R. ending in 11 hours".

Comment: Good point, @amoeba, I didn't know that was there. Why not add that as a new answer?